# Sharing the same redux code between 2 projects

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, node-modules

I have a react web app and react-native app, both share almost identical redux code (actions/services/reducers).

Is it possible to build the redux part in a different project so i'll have to maintain it only once, and then import it into the 2 projects to consume it?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it is possible, you need to create node package with action reducers and export it in index.js. This is quite complex question to answer so I will tell you how I did it.

I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-library outside web and mobile project to create node package. There you need to put your reducers, actions, const and you need to export all functions and object in index.js.

Once this is done you need to put this node module into your web app node modules. To do that I can recomend lerna which is doing this magic using bootstraping and it is creating sym links between projects.

Than createStore I used inside web and mobile app separetly since there are another reducers from another libraries which are using redux also and you can combine them.

For react-native lerna sym link is not working since metro is not able to load module outside of project in node modules to do that you need to put in metro.config.js extraNodeModules. Than your redux code can be used by your projects.